# How can you pull a value from a register?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I'm trying to figure out how to pull a register value from an ASM instruction and into a variable in C++.

For example: MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI],EDI

(Assuming value EDI holds is an int) int Value = EDI;

Comment: Of course, by the time your code executes, the value in the registers may have changed. What are you really trying to do? Perhaps you should be getting it from a context record or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on your compiler.  Search for "inline assembly" and the compiler you use.  For example with VC++

```
   int32_t x;
   _asm mov x, eax;
```

(might be __asm).  GNU uses different syntax